# Change GDIProcessHandleQuota value using c#

Tags: c#, registry, gdi+

I have tried to get the registry value using c#. I change the value but it doesn't change the actual value of my machine. When I checked my reg editor the value was still the same but when I checked my code it appears my value is changed! I don't understand the problem! is there any way to approach?

```
    private void ChangeProcessHandleQuota()
{
    const string registryKeyPath = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows";
    const string GDIProcessHandleQuotaValue = "GDIProcessHandleQuota";
    const string USERProcessHandleQuotaValue = "USERProcessHandleQuota";
    bool changedGDIProcessHandleValue = false;
    bool changedUSERProcessHandleValue = false;
    try
    {
        int currentGDIProcessHandleQuota = (int)Registry.GetValue(registryKeyPath, GDIProcessHandleQuotaValue, 0);
        int currentUSERProcessHandleQuota = (int)Registry.GetValue(registryKeyPath, USERProcessHandleQuotaValue, 0);
        if (currentGDIProcessHandleQuota == 0 || currentUSERProcessHandleQuota == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The value does not exist in the registry.", "Message");
            return;
        }
        if (currentGDIProcessHandleQuota <= 10000)
        {
            Registry.SetValue(registryKeyPath, GDIProcessHandleQuotaValue, 20000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            changedGDIProcessHandleValue = true;
        }
        if (currentUSERProcessHandleQuota <= 10000)
        {
            Registry.SetValue(registryKeyPath, USERProcessHandleQuotaValue, 20000, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            changedUSERProcessHandleValue = true;
        }
        if (changedGDIProcessHandleValue || changedUSERProcessHandleValue)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to restart your device?","Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                restartWindows();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + ex.Message, "Message");
    }
}
```